# Init and playing MPMoviePlayerController returns black screen

Tags: ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, xcode4.3

I am trying to play an mp4 video under iPhone Simulator 5.1 using some sample code from Xcode. I created both MPMovieViewController and  MPMovieController, supply a local path which contains the mp4 and add it as subview to my root controller.

When I run it under iPhone Simulator, only back screen shown. I've tried a couple of suggestions of the same problem in SO but still it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VIDEO_CX75_01" ofType:@"mp4"]];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:myURL];        
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];

    [player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
    [self.view addSubview: player.view];
    player.view.frame = self.view.frame;

    player.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
```

Where I am doing it wrong?

PS: I am on Xcode 4.3.2

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, and I what I did was made player a strong property and synthesize it. It worked.

Should work in your case as well.!

Comment: Thank you! Instant, and I would not have guessed it. (Other views and their view controllers appear to be retained as long as the view is added to another on-screen view, but apparently this one isn't. Or I did not have the parent view on-screen yet. Not sure.)

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot. I was stuck on this for 4 days. Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 0):

Decide and use either `MPMoviePlayerViewController` **or** `MPMoviePlayerController` but not both.

```
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VIDEO_CX75_01" ofType:@"mp4"]];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:myURL];        
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
```

**or**

```
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VIDEO_CX75_01" ofType:@"mp4"]];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
player.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
player.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

Comment: Tried both but it doesn't seem to work, black screen still shows instead of movie frames. PS: I've added MediaPlayer.framework and can confirm that the mp4 movie is playing through QuickTime.